# Ruby Strings, get list of compatible encodings

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, string, encoding

How can I get a list of compatible encodings for a Ruby String? (MRI 1.9.3)

Use case: I have some user provided strings, encoded with UTF-8. Ideally I need to convert them to `ISO/IEC 8859-1` (8-bit), but I also need to fallback to unicode when some special characters are present.

Also, is there a better way to accomplis this? Maybe I am testing the wrong thing.

---

**EDIT- adding more details**
Tanks for the answers, I should probably add some context.
I know how to perform encoding conversion.
I'm looking for a way to quickly find out if a string can be safely encoded to another encoding or, to put it in another (and quite wrong) way, what is the *minimum* encoding to support all the characters in that string.

Just converting the strings to 16-byte is not an option, because they will be sent as SMSs and converting them to a 16-byte encoding cuts the amount of available characters from 160 down to 70.

I need to convert them to 16-bytes only when they contain a special character which is not supported in `ISO/IEC 8859-1`.

Comment: This might help a little bit: http://yehudakatz.com/2010/05/05/ruby-1-9-encodings-a-primer-and-the-solution-for-rails/

Comment: That's not a use case... just using a unicode encoding in the first place will be effectively the same but simpler

Comment: @Esailija Thanks, if I could I'd do it. I can't use unicode in the first place because I need to minimize the size of the strings. I'm working with [SMPP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SMPP) and need to build a byte buffer from the strings. I should use a 16-bit encoding as a last resort.

Comment: I see.. I thought you were talking about using different internal encodings.. converting to any encoding on output is ok

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unluckily, Ruby’s ideas of encoding compatibility are not fully congruent with your use case. However, trying to encode your UTF-8 string in ISO-8859-1 and catching the error that is thrown when a conversion is not possible will achieve what you are after:

```
begin
  'your UTF-8 string'.encode!('ISO-8859-1')
rescue Encoding::UndefinedConversionError
end
```

will convert your string to ISO-8859-1 if possible and leave it as UTF-8 if not.

Note this uses `encode`, which actually *transcodes* the string using `Encoding::Converter` (i.e. reassigns the correct encoding byte pattern to the character representations of the string), unlike `force_encoding`, which just changes the encoding *flag* (i.e. tells Ruby to interpret the string’s byte stream according to the set encoding).

Answer (score 2):

Ruby has [standard library](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/index.html) in which u can find class [Encoding](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Encoding.html) and his sub-class called [Encoding::Converter](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Encoding/Converter.html) they are probably your best friends in this case.

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
# encoding: utf-8

converter = Encoding::Converter.new("UTF-8", "ISO-8859-1")
converted = converter.convert("é")

puts converted.encoding
# => ISO-8859-1

puts converted.dump
# => "\xE9"
```

Answer (score 2):

Is `valid_encoding?` ([instance method of String](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-valid_encoding-3F)) useful? That is:

```
try_str = str.force_encoding("ISO/IEC 8859-1")
str = try_str if try_str.valid_encoding?
```

Comment: This will test for binary compatibility, which only amounts to character compatibility in the ASCII lower pane (aka ASCII-7-BIT). OP is asking for representational compatibility, i.e. a way to test which non-single-byte UTF-8 encoded characters can be mapped to ISO-8859-1 single-byte encoding. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14348119/990363) for a solution that actually does that.

Answer (score -1):

To convert to `ISO-8859-1` you can follow the below code to encode it.

```
1.9.3p194 :002 > puts "é".force_encoding("ISO-8859-1").encode("UTF-8")
Ã©
 => nil
```

[Linked Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14196455/how-to-intentionally-insert-strings-with-the-wrong-encoding-in-mysql/14196580#14196580)

Answer (score -1):

```
"Some String".force_encoding("ISO/IEC 8859-1")
```

Also you can refer [rails encoding link](http://yehudakatz.com/2010/05/05/ruby-1-9-encodings-a-primer-and-the-solution-for-rails/)